# Pushing to the top of a Kendo Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mvvm

I am currently using Kendo Mobile, and Kendo MVVM to create a native looking browser app.
I am using Kendos source and template binding, and I am trying to do something very simple, but cant seem to figure it out.  What I want to do is push a new item to my already existing array which works, but I would like the item to go to the top of the list not the bottom. Is there a way to reorder a kendo array once I have pushed to it, or can I explicitly tell my item to push to the top.

Here is my jquery which works, but its pushing to the bottom I want it at the top.

```
 newsfeedvm.get("posts").push({
                visibleDelete: false,
                myPost: data.IsMine,
                auththemecolor: { defaultC: data.DefaultColor, lightC: data.LightColor, darkC: data.DarkColor, },
                authpicture: data.AuthorURL,
                authdisplayname: data.PostDisplayName,
                posttime: data.DisplayTime,
                postcontent: data.PostContent,
                numberComments: data.CommentCount,
                postId: data.Id
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `newsfeedvm.get("posts")` is returning a regular Array, you can try the `unshift` method. It basically does the same thing as `push`, except it adds the item to the beginning of the array. Documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Kendo observable arrays seem to support it as well:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/observablearray#methods-unshift

Comment: Thanks man that worked great! Like I said so simple, I was just over looking it